# How can I run a "hello world" on webassembly with the latest Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webassembly

I'm making this question after reading the [official documentation](http://webassembly.org/) and not finding this information.

I'm on Node.js `v8.1.3`. How do I compile and run a "hello world" on wast (WebAssembly's textual representation) from within JavaScript on Node.js?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you have an existing hello world program written in (wast textual format)? It's not too hard to compile that to wasm (binary format) using external tools so I'm assuming your question is really about performing the wast to wasm compilation step from within node.js?

Comment: This has nothing to do with textual "hello world". I just wanted a small, complete snippet on how to run any WASM at all. I was having a lot of trouble getting set up. I eventually managed to, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [node-wasm](https://github.com/yusinto/node-wasm) to load your wasm file and then in your node js app, do this:

```
import loadWasm from 'node-wasm';

async function run() {
  const {rust_function} = await loadWasm('/local/path/to/wasm');
  const result = rust_function();
  console.log(result);
}

run();
```

There's a complete example [here](https://github.com/yusinto/node-wasm/tree/master/example/node) in the same repo. Good luck!